# Staging environment for pages only

Tags: staging

I am currently developing a news-style website. I am using Softaculous to build changes in a staging environment and then pushing to live when they are ready.

Ideally, however, I would like to stage changes to the site's *pages* while simultaneously keeping the production site updated with articles (ie, posts and images).

Changes I would like to stage, besides additional/edited pages, would be changes to themes and plugins. Ie, everything except posts an d the media library.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

From what I can tell Softaculous doesn't so much as merge as simply push from staging to production — so if I were to update any posts on product and then push to live, those posts would get overwritten/removed after the site updates.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're happy at the command line you may want to look at staging themes and plugins using git-based workflow as this is mostly about updating files. Pages are database content (plus files too if there is media), and I don't know of an easy solution here.

Comment: Yes, I use Git regularly over a CLI, although I've never used it with Wordpress. But [this](https://45royale.com/blog/wordpress-github/) looks fairly straightforward. And as you say it would be a perfect way to just pull in the file changes while keeping the MySQL updated directly from the site (and because it's a pull rather than an overwrite I could keep the directly added images). Thanks!